# Parse url of json into a list containing all values from a particular json key in python

Tags: python, json

I have a url in json format here: http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/genenames/hgnc/json/locus_groups/protein-coding_gene.json, and I'm trying to retrieve all of the values of the key "symbol" (not alias_symbol or prev_symbol) and put them into a list, but I'm not exactly sure how.

I have something to grab the json from the url right now

```
response = requests.get("http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/genenames/hgnc/json/locus_groups/protein-coding_gene.json")
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

but I'm not sure how to parse the data into the list of symbol values.

Comment: Jeese. That's alot of data...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with list comprehension:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/genenames/hgnc/json/locus_groups/protein-coding_gene.json")
data = response.json()
symbols = [i['symbol'] for i in data['response']['docs']]
```

But given the amount of data you might want to work with `pandas` to keep oversight:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data['response']['docs'])
symbols = df['symbol'].tolist()
```